# How should I go about reading a large binary file

Tags: c++, windows, binary

I have a large binary file (more than 500mb) that I want to read a part of and extract data from. I'm sure I shouldn't load the whole file into memory all at once, so how could I load only a part of it, using hex offsets?

I've never worked with this kind of thing before, so I have no idea where to start. All I want to read and write to the file is text.

Comment: If you know the offset (the human representation of this offset, be it octal, decimal, or hex is totally irrelevant) then just seek to that part of the file and read the correct number of bytes. If this doesn't make sense to you, it's time for [a new book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thank you. No, that makes sense to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: He is working with text, so seeking may not be an option...

Comment: It says *binary* file in the question...

Comment: @Sean: It's a binary file, but all you want to read and write is text? Huh?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry for the confusion. I meant I wanted to write hex that in the end is represented as text. You, ultimately I want to take the hex in the file, convert it to a string, then display it in a list.

Comment: Hex offsets? Are they more efficient than decimal offsets?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Kerrek: They're _prettier_! And can take you so much further...

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, as I'm using a hex editor, it's just more simple to use hex offsets.

Comment: I understand HEX better than Decimal actually. Helps me do the math fast.

Comment: @Sean: To decode the banter, there is no such thing as a "hex offset". There is just an offset, which is a number, which you can write in decimal or hex or whatever. If you want to write them in hex that's fine, but it doesn't make them "hex offsets". </pedantic> :)

Comment: @Aniket: Primary school must have been frustrating.

Comment: @Aniket I'm making a program to use with translation a Playstation 1 ISO. I have a text table that converts the "encrypted" hex into text, I just need to make a program so that a user can edit the file.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no, primary school was facinating. High school was MORE facinating :P

Comment: So you're basically making a hex editor. Memory mapped file is how you go. :) @SeanHeiss

Comment: @Aniket OK, that sounds good. :) Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [Memory Mapped File.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) This will allow you to process the file as if it were in memory, but it only ever gets loaded into memory a page at a time.

Comment: might also want to link [``mmap``](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) for posix OSs, but the idea is just right :)

Comment: It does get loaded into memory, just one page at a time.

Comment: Great! That sounds perfect. Do you know of a guide or any other resource for using these in C++?

Comment: @Alex, correct - but it never gets totally loaded to memory. Thanks

Comment: @OtávioDécio That's for C#/VB. What about for C++?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37201/Simple-File-I-O-Using-Windows-Memory-Mapped-Files